# Illegal operator and value combination

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

in this section $rekap_garduinduk = GarduInduk::whereDate('waktu_trip', '>=', $start_date)
have errors "Illegal operator and value combination." what did i do?

`rekap-garduinduk.blade.php`

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ url('/rekap-garduinduk') }}">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="start_date">Start Date :</label>
                                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="end_date">End Date :</label>
                                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-3" id="area">
                                <label for="area">Search Area:</label>
                                <select class="form-control">
                                    <option value="UP3">-- UP3 / UP2D --</option>
                                    <option value="Up2d">UP2D</option>
                                    <option value="Cilacap">Cilacap</option>
                                    <option value="Demak">Demak</option>
                                    <option value="Klaten">Klaten</option>
                                    <option value="Kudus">Kudus</option>
                                    <option value="Magelang">Magelang</option>
                                    <option value="Pekalongan">Pekalongan</option>
                                    <option value="Purwokerto">Purwokerto</option>
                                    <option value="Salatiga">Salatiga</option>
                                    <option value="Semarang">Semarang</option>
                                    <option value="Sukoharjo">Sukoharjo</option>
                                    <option value="Surakarta">Surakarta</option>
                                    <option value="Tegal">Tegal</option>
                                    <option value="Yogyakarta">Yogyakarta</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="margin-top:29px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

`TablesController.php`

```
public function RekapGarduIndukSearch(Request $request)
    {
        $start_date = $request->start_date;
        $end_date = $request->end_date;

        $rekap_garduinduk = GarduInduk::whereDate('waktu_trip', '>=', $start_date)
            ->whereDate('waktu_trip', '<=', $end_date)
            ->orWhereDate('waktu_normal', '>=', $start_date)
            ->orWhereDate('waktu_normal', '<=', $end_date)
            ->get();


        return view('backend.tables.rekap-garduinduk', compact('rekap_garduinduk'));
    }
```

`web.php`

Route::get('/rekap-garduinduk', [App\Http\Controllers\backend\TablesController::class, 'RekapGarduIndukSearch'])->name('RekapGarduIndukSearch');